# Count the number of specific days of the month that have passed since a given date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a function in SQL Server 2012 that will need to know the number of 3 specific days of the month that have passed since a given date.  I can do this with a while loop, but its slow and I was looking for a better way. 
Here is what I have so far:

> Let's assume that GETDATE() = '11/14/2016' and @productDate = '10/1/2016'

```
    --Get the number of "units" that have passed since the date on the label
DECLARE @unitCount INT = 0;
DECLARE @countingDate DATE 
SET @countingDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@productDate);--add 1 to prevent counting the date on the label as the first unit
WHILE (@countingDate < CAST(GETDATE() As date ))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @unitCount = @unitCount + 
            CASE
                WHEN DAY(@countingDate) = 1 OR DAY(@countingDate) = 10 OR DAY(@countingDate) = 20 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        SET @countingDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@countingDate);
    END
```

> This will result in @unitCount = 4
>
> GETDATE() of '11/20/2016' would result in @unitCount = 5

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?  i.e. sample input and desired results

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. And it's helpful to _tag_ database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a numbers table

```
create function dbo.fn_DateCounter
(
    @datefrom date,
    @dateto date
)
returns int 
as 
begin
    return 
    -- number of complete months
    3 * 
    (
        (DATEPART(YYYY, @dateto) * 12 + DATEPART(MM, @dateto)) 
        -(DATEPART(YYYY, @datefrom) * 12 + DATEPART(MM, @datefrom))      
        - 1
    )
    -- add on the extras from the first month
    + case when DATEPART(DD, @datefrom) < 10 then 2
           when DATEPART(DD, @datefrom) < 20 then 1
           else 0
    end
    -- add on the extras from the last month
    + case when DATEPART(DD, @dateto) > 20 then 3
           when DATEPART(DD, @dateto) > 10 then 2
           else 1 
    end

end
go

select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','01-jan-2000') -- 0 
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','10-jan-2000') -- 0 
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','11-jan-2000') -- 1
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','20-jan-2000') -- 1
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','21-jan-2000') -- 2
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('11-jan-2000','21-jan-2000') -- 1
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('11-jan-2000','21-feb-2000') -- 4
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','01-jan-2001') -- 36
select dbo.fn_DateCounter('01-jan-2000','11-jan-2001') -- 37
```

Comment: +1, good answer. Note that functions tend to have similar issues to loops in that they can be slow, but this does have the benefit of being concise (outside of the function), and is not limited to a time frame like my answer. Also note that you can shorten this some by replacing  `DATEPART(xx)` with `MONTH()`, `DAY()`, or `YEAR()`

Comment: @JamesCasey This is very close and runs much faster than the WHILE loop.  To get my expected output, I changed the last part to 'case when DATEPART(DD, @dateto) >= 20 then 3
           when DATEPART(DD, @dateto) >= 10 then 2
           else 1 '

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `sum`, `case`, and the `dbo.spt_values` table:

```
declare @productDate datetime = '11/01/2016',
    @unitCount int

;with nums as ( -- use a CTE to build a number list
    select top 1000 number from master..spt_values
)

select  @unitCount = sum( 
            case    when day(dateadd(day, n, @productDate)) in (1, 10, 20) 
                    then 1 else 0 end
    ) -- add 1 for each 1,10,20 we find
from (
    select  n = row_number() over (order by nums.number)
    from    nums cross join nums as num -- 1000*1000 = 1 million rows
) n
where   dateadd(day, n, @productDate) < getdate()

select  @unitCount
```

This will grab each date between `@productDate` and `getdate()`. The `case` statement will `select 1` for each 1/10/20, and 0 for every other date. Finally, we take the `sum` of the result.

For `11/1 - 11/11`, it returns 1. 
For `1/1 - 11/11`, the result is 31.

EDIT: In the CTE (`with nums as...`), we select `1-1000`, and then we do a `cross join` which gives us a million records to work with. The answer is still limited, but now you can go ~2700 years with this.